# Are there any points I have to be aware of to program on 64 bit box (c/c++)?

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I mean the main differences to program c/c++ on 64 bit box from 32 bit box. Sorry if this question is somewhat subjective and any feedbacks are appreciated~

Comment: What do you mean specifically? If you're writing basic programs, there's nothing really. The C/C++ compiler should generate code for both platforms just fine. The only thing I can think of is maybe, accounting for integer size differences?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the architecture and the program. If you've been using the platform-neutral types that C and C++ offer when applicable (`size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, etc.), have not made assumptions regarding the size of `int`, `long`, etc., and have not tried to store pointers in `int` variables and similar hacks, then you should be fine.